# ftt data for waterfall plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I used periodogram in Matlab to perform vibration analysis.  I wanted to see how the frequencies changed with time during vibration, and I believed I should use waterfall plot or other 3D plot.  My question is how I can save the amplitude data from ftt into a matrix (m,n). m is number of the data point from each calculation, n is the number of time interval for each calculation with periodogram.

I learned how to plot waterfall plot or other 3D plot in Matlab, but do not know how to save the amplitude data into a matrix. Did some search, but with no luck.

Comment: Do you have any sample code?

Comment: Sample code would be goof. Pre-allocate your result matrix `R` of size `m x n`. For each iteration step `i` store in the i-th column: `R(:, i) = abs( fft( data(i) ) )`

Comment: Thanks very much Matthias.